# C++: name of a value may have linkage

Tags: c++, enums, linkage, compile-time-constant

Extracted from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> A name that denotes object, reference, function, type, template,
>   namespace, or **value**, may have *linkage*.

What is "the name of a value"? Can anybody provide an example where a name of a value is not a name of an object?

Comment: Maybe enumerators?

Comment: @KerrekSB they can have linkage?

Comment: @PasserBy: I'm not sure. Enumerators have names, the names denote values, and the names can be declared in different scopes. But it's not stated explicitly in the standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB Enums introduce named constants. The standard is explicit about that.

Comment: @skypjack and I guess they are the only named values isn't? Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Peregring-lk There is already another answer that is almost there. No reason to post something so close to it just to gain reputation. I added a comment to the other one around. Let's see if the owner integrates it.

Answer (score 0):

One example of something close to this would be an [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)'s values, although technically they are [named constants](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#1):

```
enum class example
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO
}
```

In this case, the enum `example` has names that are values where `ONE` corresponds to 1, and `TWO` corresponds to 2.

These aren't just variables since you can't assign to them.

Lastly, according to the link you posted, the enumerators have external linkage.

Comment: Technically they are [named constants](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#1).

Comment: @skypjack Edited.